# What am I doing wrong in measuring execution time using RDTSC and CPUID instructions?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, att, rdtsc

I'm a C++ student and I was assigned to measure the time of memory allocation of 1.000.000 integers, using CPUID and RDTSC instructions in inline assembly for G++ compiler. Here is the code I came up with:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned cycles_high1=0, cycles_low1=0, cpuid_time=0;
    unsigned cycles_high2=0, cycles_low2=0;
    unsigned  temp_cycles1=0, temp_cycles2=0;
    unsigned total_cycles=0;
     
    asm volatile(
        "cpuid\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%edx\n\t"
        "mov %1, %%eax\n\t"
        "cpuid\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"

        "cpuid\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%edx\n\t"
        "mov %1, %%eax\n\t"
        "cpuid\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"

        "cpuid\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%edx\n\t"
        "mov %1, %%eax\n\t"
        "cpuid\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"

        "sub %%eax, %1\n\t"
        "mov %2, %%eax\n\t"
        : "=r" (cycles_high1), "=r" (cycles_low1), "=r" (cpuid_time)
        :
        : "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"
    );

    cycles_high1=0;
    cycles_low1=0;
    
    asm(
        "cpuid\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%edx\n\t"
        "mov %1, %%eax\n\t"
        : "=r" (cycles_high1), "=r" (cycles_low1)
        :
        : "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"
    );

    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000000);

    asm(
        "cpuid\n\t"
        "rdtsc\n\t"
        "mov %0, %%edx\n\t"
        "mov %1, %%eax\n\t"
        : "=r" (cycles_high2), "=r" (cycles_low2)
        :
        : "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx"
    );

    temp_cycles1 = ((unsigned long long)cycles_high1 << 32) | cycles_low1;
    temp_cycles2 = ((unsigned long long)cycles_high2 << 32) | cycles_low2;
    total_cycles = temp_cycles2 - temp_cycles1 - cpuid_time; 

    cout << total_cycles;

    return 0;
}
```

The structure of the asm code was provided to me in Windows Visual Studio compiler asm syntax, and I adapted it to G++ asm syntax.  Firstly I am calculating the CPUID overhead time in 'cpuid_time' and at the end subtracting from the total measured time.

The output is always 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why cast the `cycles_high1` variable to an `unsigned long long` before the shift and bitwise OR operations, only to assign the result of that calculation to a plain old `unsigned` (which is the type of `temp_cycles1` in your code). Same with the following line. Maybe close this as a typo? Not sure.

Comment: You also have a lot of seemingly redundant `cpuid` and `rdtsc` instructions in your first `asm` block ... but maybe I'm overlooking something subtle going on, there.

Comment: Assuming a 32-bit `unsigned` type (which is what I think g++ uses), then the `temp_cycles1 = ((unsigned long long)cycles_high1 << 32) | cycles_low1;` line is just doing `temp_cycles1 = cycles_low1;` .. with a dash of added UB, for good measure.

Comment: I modified the code such that temp_cycles1 is of type *unsigned long long* (I need it to be on 64 bits, that is how it was written in the Windows Visual Studio asm code from the TA).

Comment: You didn't modify the code you've shown here.

Comment: This is a port of [My GCC \_\_rdtsc() method of calculating clock cycles returns me a totally different result than Microsoft inline assembly rdtsc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77422102) I think?  Looks like you got your AT&T syntax backwards. `mov src, dst`.  Or better, just tell the compiler which register you want the output in, as in the `rdtsc()` function that wraps one rdtsc with inline asm in [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567)

Comment: @Peter How do you know I need AT&T syntax and not Intel syntax?

Comment: I can tell it's AT&T because you're decorating register names with `%`, like `%%edx` which (after the compiler processes the template string) will become `%edx` in the compiler-generated `.s` file.  Also, you didn't mention using `gcc -masm=intel`, and AT&T is the default for GCC and clang.  And leaving output registers unmodified would pretty easily explain the symptoms.